# Webcam only has 1080p resolution recognized on Safari, but not on Firefox or Chrome

Tags: macos, browser, resolution, webcam, hardware-detection

I bought a [UVC webcam](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B087WP4W6F) which claims to have 1080p resolution, but with Firefox (my default browser) I can only detect 720p (I used the [WebRTC-based test here](https://webrtchacks.github.io/WebRTC-Camera-Resolution/)). I thought it's a case of deceptive description, and ordered another one from a different brand, but it turned out to be even worse.

Then I did the test with Chrome and Safari. Amazingly, each test returned different results, and only when using Safari did the result report support for 1080p.

So maybe the seller didn't really lie, but what happened exactly? Is there a way for me to get 1080p consistently or is it a case of needing special drivers on MacOS? Or is the camera pretending to support 1080p?

By the way, even though Safari reports support for 1080p, in Google Hangout with Safari I can still only choose 720p as the maximum upload resolution. I would also like to figure out why.

Attached are the results I got from different browsers:

[image: Safari Results]

[image: Firefox Results]

[image: Chrome Results]